# In Swift 3, how to display images from link to local file directory in tableviewcell

Tags: swift, local-storage

I want to save images in local file not on server and displays those images in UItableviewcell via link to that file\folder.
I am not sure what path i used to save in database. I am saving imagefolder in desktop.But that path: /desktop/imagefolder/image.jpg not working.

Answer (score 0):

iOS apps have access only to sandbox , that mean you write only in the folder Document , Temp and Library . [See the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html).

Here an exemple how to write and read an image in documents directory.

```
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let path = "\(documentsDirectory)/image.png"
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path)
```

And now how to save:

```
let image = ...
let documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
let path = "\(documentsDirectory)/image.png"
if let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!) {
    try? data.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
}
```